# django url parameter creating in the process

Tags: json, django, django-views, django-urls

I have no idea how to solve this problem:

I have a django webshop project. At the end of the order I would like to redirect the user to a new page about the confirmation.

urls.py:

```
`path('confirmation/<str:order_id>/', views.confirmation,` name="confirmation"),
```

views.py:

```
def confirmation(request, order_id):
    
    items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__id = order_id)

    context = {'items':items}
    return render(request, 'store/pages/confirmation.html', context)
```

I have a javascript part another view where I do a POST method. If it is successfully done I would like to navigate to the confirmation page.
In the `data` I get back the `order_id`.

```
var url = '/process_order/'
        fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },            
            body: JSON.stringify({'myForm':myFormData})
        })
            

        .then((response) => response.json())           
        .then((data) => {                                            
            window.location.href = "{% url 'confirmation' data %}"   
            })
```

I guess the problem is that in the very beginning of the execution there is no value of the `data`, because it is creating in the process. So the view can not render because of the parameter. (But my problem is that the `order_id` is creating after the POST method).

(The Exception Value:
`Reverse for 'confirmation' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['confirmation/(?P<order_id>[^/]+)/$']` )

What would be the good solution of this situation?

Comment: generate your URL in JavaScript instead

Comment: why are you passing `data` in confirmation `url` ?

Comment: Share your `process_order`. It must be return the redirect url.

Comment: Remove order id in url and use order in post data

Comment: According to @iklinac 's suggestion I tried the way to navigate to the confirmation page with JavaScript.
It is working but not so nice, because I had to burn the hard link in the code. (And need to change before production) :/

window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/purchase_confirmation/"+data+"/"

Progam:  because I need the order details in the confirmation page. In data I only pass the order_id.

NKSM: I can not redirect from process_order because I need to return back first to the POST method.